# How do I pass (or reference) "$(this)" from html event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have a button **in a table** which adds a new row to a table:

`<td><a onclick="addRow()"></a></td></tr>...`

and I want to reference `$(this)` or `$(this).closest('tr')` from the function at the bottom of the page.

```
function addRow(){
   $(this) // contains all information from the row which pressed the button

}
```

Simply passing a javascript variable from the HTML will result in null (as expected). Is there a way to reference the row that pressed the button?

Comment: Just search for it from where you clicked on it. Or attach the click handler to the row.

Comment: Handler handler! Let's let "onclick="javaScriptFunction()"` die... Hooray for `addEventListener`! (or `$(selector).on('click', stuff)`, if you're into jQuery...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this`

`<td><a onclick="addRow(this)"></a></td></tr>`

and then:

```js
function addRow(e){
   console.log($(e)) // contains all information from the row which pressed the button
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a onclick="addRow(this)">Clickme</a>
```

Comment: No need to downvote this. Sure it's not the most modern or best practice, but there are situations where it's the only solution and it's by no means a wrong answer.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I agree, but in my case specifically, I need to be able to reference it from HTML without creating a jQuery event.

Comment: Fair enough then :)

Comment: @Jordan If you are able to write a JS function at the "bottom of the page" then why not rely on jQuery delegation and event handling when you have jQuery anyway?

Answer (score 4):

The RECOMMENDED way of doing this is unobtrusive and delegated - give the link a class:

```js
var $tb = $("#someTable");

$tb.on("click", ".addRow", function(e) { // delegation to allow new rows' links to work
  e.preventDefault(); // stop any click side effects
  var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
  $tb.append($row.clone())
});
```

```css
a { text-decoration:none }
td,th { padding:3px }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>Add</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="someTable">
    <tr>
      <td>1st</td>
      <td>2nd</td>
      <td><a class="addRow" href="#">+</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3rd</td>
      <td>4th</td>
      <td><a class="addRow" href="#">+</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the row that you clicked using an event.

```
<td><a href="javascript:addRow(this)">Add</a></td>
```

and in javascript you can check the event

```
<script>
    function addRow(event) {
      console.log(event);

    }
  </script>
```